# expect script is not sending correct value

Tags: expect

I wrote an expect script which will connect to a server and send a password depending on the prompt. The purpose is to update my password on new servers.

Basically, it will connect to a new server, expect to see `(current) UNIX password:` and then send my initial password. It will then see the 'New password:`and 'Retype new password:` prompts sending the new password each time.

My script loads these passwords from files into variables `$pw1` and `$pw2`. I have evaluated them and verified that I have the correct values loaded into the variables. However, when I run the script, I am getting a `token manipulation error` on the initial password which tells me the value being sent is incorrect.

Perhaps my logic is incorrect?

**EDIT:** I have connected to one server that I'm running the script against and entered the old password exactly as it is in the file that the script loads into `$pw2`. It is working so I know that the password is not incorrect.

```
#! /usr/bin/expect --

#exp_internal 1
#set stty_init raw
set timeout 45
set prompt {\$ $}
set file1 [open [lindex $argv 0] r]
set pw1 [exec cat /home/user/bin/.pw1.txt]
set pw2 [exec cat /home/user/bin/.pw2.txt]
#puts $pw1
#puts $pw2

while {[gets $file1 host] != -1} {
    puts $host
    spawn -noecho ssh -q $host
    expect {
        "*assword*" {
            send -- "$pw1\r"
            expect {
                $prompt {
                    send -- exit\r
                } 
            }
            send -- exit\r
            expect eof
        }
        -re $prompt {
            send -- exit\r
            expect eof
        }
        "(current)*" {
            send -- "$pw2\r"
            expect "New password"
            send -- "$pw1\r"
            expect "Retype new password"
            send -- "$pw1\r"
            puts \r
        }
        "continue*" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect {
                "current" {
                    send -- "$pw2\r"
                    expect "New password"
                    send -- "$pw1\r"
                    expect "Retype new password"
                    send -- "$pw1\r"
                    puts \r
#                   expect eof
                }
                -re $prompt {
                    send -- exit\r
                    expect eof
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

puts \r
```

Comment: Can you try with `exp_internal 1` and check the debug output ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to note that you don't need to nest `expect` commands: look into the `exp_continue` command, instead. It will cut your code size in half simply by eliminating duplication.

Second, it looks your logic is, indeed, wrong. The first expect pattern is `"*assword*"`. I would expect this to match when the remote server of your `ssh` is prompting for the user's current password, and it sends `$pw1`. However, everywhere else in your code, you seem to be treating `$pw2` as the current password, and `$pw1` as the *new* password.

Also, when you rewrite your code using `exp_continue` to eliminate the duplication and nesting, make sure you re-order your patterns so they're listed in order of most specific to least specific. Otherwise, you'll sometimes find the wrong pattern being matched, and the wrong code being executed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow what you're saying. I've read up on how to use `exp_continue` but it isn't clear to me. Where would I put it and would it go somewhere in place of something else?